Passing an image from kotlin to a python library using chaquopy
I'm trying to pass an image from from my kotlin to python, image selection and adding to state is simple, image selection is done using rememberLauncherForActivityResult() method,
then I save the selected image in the app's internal directory,
then I try to pass the image path which stored in a mutable state,
when I check using println on kotlin it shows the the image path that from app internal storage,
when it comes to python their nothing,
also python chaquopy is integrated and appropriate implementation is done on the gradle file,
I gesss.
if anyone, professional at native android development, please show you suggestion and give a try to share the logic code

Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your code, both on the Kotlin and Python sides. And also the debug print output from both sides.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
